# What's wrong with my regex replace functions?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

```js
    var storeName = "St. Bob's Store";
    var storeId = storeName.replace(/./g,"").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/'/g,"")
    $('#storeName').html(storeName)
    $('#storeId').html("(" + storeId + ")")
    
    console.log("Updating " + storeName + "(" + storeId + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="storeName">Loading</div>
<div id="storeId">loading</div>
```

What am I doing wrong with `storeId`?  It's empty.

Comment: If your intent is to replace the dot in storeName, you need to escape it in the regex.  A dot means "any single character".

Comment: Keep in mind that expert's exchange != expert sex change.  Same storeId though!

Comment: lol thanks, but this won't be a problem in my case :)

Comment: Although I do have a customer named Pen Island... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match "dot" char, you have to escape it, like this:

```
var storeId = storeName.replace(/\./g,"").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/'/g,"");
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e63bq01L/

If not escaped, the dot matches **all characters** in a string.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the dot character:

```
storeName.replace(/\./g,"").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/'/g,"")
```

Otherwise, you will replace everything.